# dataframe: automatically add the index whenever a new row is created

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV that is a dataframe in the following format

```
index location
1       NY
2       AUS
```

Is there a way for me to use
df.append() , where I just give the location and the index is automatically added,in this case , I just provide a city for example TEX , and then the dataframe should be

```
index location
1       NY
2       AUS
3       TEX
```

Comment: is index a column or the index? do you have a range? Should it start from 1? You can use `concat` with `ignore_index` (but this will start from 0). NB. `append` is getting deprecated

Comment: index is not `0,1,2` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom method to create a new record on your dataframe:

```
def append_location(df, location):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [df['index'].max() + 1],
                        'location': [location]})
    return pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

df = append_location(df, 'TEX')
print(df)

# Output:
   index location
0      1       NY
1      2      AUS
2      3      TEX
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2], 
                   'location': ['NY', 'AUS']})
print(df)

# Output
   index location
0      1       NY
1      2      AUS
```